# Vue v-for with Bulma Dropdown menus

Tags: vue.js, bulma

I have a project using vue-cli + Bulma as the CSS framework

```
                 <div v-for="(input, index) in menuInputs" class="input-wrapper-items">
                        <div class="field custom-control">
                            <label class="label">{{input.label}} # {{index + 1}}</label>
                            <!--<div class="control">-->
                                <!--<input name="itemName" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Item Name">-->
                            <!--</div>-->
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                                    <button class="button" v-on:click="magic()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
                                        <span>First word</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" v-bind:id="input.ID+1" role="menu">
                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <p class="dropdown-item" v-for="option in soundOptions">
                                            {{option}}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                                    <button class="button" v-on:click="magic()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu2">
                                        <span>Second word</span>

                                        <!--<span class="icon is-small">-->
                                        <!--&lt;!&ndash;fontawesome required for the icon&ndash;&gt;-->
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
                                        <!--</span>-->
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu2" v-bind:id="input.ID+2" role="menu">
                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <p class="dropdown-item" v-for="option in soundOptions">
                                            {{option}}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have a main `v-for` loop at the top which is going to generate a series of two side by side drop-down menus.

The issue is associating each drop `down-trigger` with the correct `drop-down` menu it is associated to.

I am not sure what I can increment in order to give each trigger/menu pair their own unique ID's in order for them to be independently associated.

Comment: `2 * index` and `2 * index + 1`?

Comment: @StephenThomas Are you suggesting something like this?
`v-bind:id="2 * index"`